# Marginnote causing unwanted indent

Tags: indentation, marginnote

I am writing an exam and am using the following code to insert the marks for the question on the right in the margin.

```
\newcommand{\mrks}[1]{
    \marginnote{\textbf{#1}}[0em]
    \ignorespaces
}
```

When I build the code, it causes an indent to occur at the location of the `\mrks` command. For the command `\mrks{1}`, an indent one character wide is inserted. This is occurring inside the questions environment as defined below.

```
% question style
\newenvironment{questions}{
    % change margins for marks
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{10mm}

    % short answer labels
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{
        \textbf{\arabic{enumi}}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}

    % set questions indent and alignment
    \setlist[enumerate]{
        align=parleft,
        labelindent=0em
    }    
    
    % set space between questions
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{
        itemsep=0em
    }
    
    % set alignment of question parts
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{
        align=right,
        itemsep=0em,
        topsep=1em,
        labelsep=1em,
    }

    \begin{enumerate}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
```

Any idea how I can remove the indent?

Comment: you have defined `\newcommand{\mrks}[1]{SPACE\marginnote{\textbf{#1}}[0em]`